# Cayley tables and cyclic subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Given a Cayley table, how can I spot the subgroups, without missing any of them? I know which orders of subgroups that I should look for because of Lagrange's theorem, but how can I create an exhaustive list of subgroups without skipping any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsets of the group are created by deleting elements from the group (obviously).  This amounts to deleting a row and column from the corresponding Cayley table.  Now, you can tell if this new Cayley table represents a group by the following criterion:  If each element in the subset appears exactly once in a row and column, then the resulting Cayley table represents a group (more specifically a subgroup of the original group).  Stated differently, the rows (and columns) of a Cayley table for a group are simply permutations of the elements of the group.

Comment: But is there some sort of 'formula' that can give me the number of subgroups of a group?

Comment: In general, no (or at least not that I am aware of).  If the group is finite abelian, I believe you could use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups to tell you how many subgroups there are.  But this is just one special class.